# If the value for the variables username:password are password:password what hash algorithm is being used here?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash, decode

If the values for the variables username:password are "password:password" what algorithm gives the following hash for the actual password, given hashed password =
C1AEDCA5FB2768A52A98C2D925EE8212

Username and password are both used to create hash.

Comment: MD4 or MD5 (probably MD5).

Comment: @Yonlif It doesn't seem to be MD5 when trying to crack here https://hashkiller.co.uk/Cracker/MD5 or at https://crackstation.net/

Comment: @knowledstack  It's difficult/impractical to crack anything of that sort without trying multiple hash techniques. But, what is the question?

Comment: If they're using a salt, or some type of secret key, there's no way you're going to crack this.

Comment: @vivek_23 If you can't crack it it does not mean it is not MD5... When running it through hash identifier it says MD5.

Comment: @Yonlif It's just a 128 bit value. There's no way to say what algorithm generated it.

Comment: @JimMischel well you are sort of correct but there are some ways [to identify hash types](https://miloserdov.org/?p=1254).

Comment: @Yonlif Yes, if the output is in some recognizable format, then you can infer the hash type. But a bare 128-bit value such as the OP supplied could have been generated by anything. Saying that it was generated by MD5 is kind of like saying that if you got the value 4, you got it by adding 2 and 2.